# Get a table with barcodes with zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks, barcode

I'd need to display (and print later) a page with a table containing a barcode and description each row.

I have my

```
$result = $mySql->query->fetchAll();
```

containing the right data.

at first I made a

```
$rendererOptions = array();
    foreach($result as &$res){
        $barcodeOptions = array(
                'text' => $res['myParam'],
                'rendererParams' => array('imageType' => 'gif'),);
        $res['barcode'] = Zend_Barcode::factory('CODE39', 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions)->draw();
}

    $this->view->data = $result;
```

with bad results. Then I tried with:

```
Zend_Barcode::render(....);
```

with many combinations, even a

```
$.post('/mycontroller/myactionthatrendersthebarcode',{code : this.id}, function(data){
            $(this).html(data);     });
```

in my .phtml page (almost killing the network :D )

Following the docs( http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.barcode.creation.html ) 
I only got a single, but right, barcode or a bunch of resources Ids I don't know how manage.

Any advice?
Thank you

Comment: what means `bad results`? Do you get an exception/error?

Comment: No simply a corrupted image logo or no results at all.
The only thing I understood is I miss the "logical method" to do that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `draw` method returns an gd image resource. To output the image you can do:

```
$rendererOptions = array();
$barcodeOptions = array(
    'text' => 'TEST',
    'rendererParams' => array('imageType' => 'gif'),
);
$resource = Zend_Barcode::factory('CODE39', 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions)->draw();

header('Content-Type: image/gif');
imagegif($resource);
exit;
```

The `render` method do it automatically for you:

```
$rendererOptions = array();
$barcodeOptions = array(
    'text' => 'TEST',
    'rendererParams' => array('imageType' => 'gif'),
);
Zend_Barcode::factory('CODE39', 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions)->render();
exit;
```

If you want to output the image in an `img` tag you have to write the above into an action and call it. So for example the above script is in `outputAction` in `ImgController`

```
<img src="/img/output">
```

If you want it dynamically you can send get params to the action and do the logic in the action.

```
<img src="/img/output/text/TEXT">
<img src="/img/output/id/123">
```